# Add Favicon with React and Webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, favicon

I am attempting to add a favicon to a React-based website that I made using webpack. It has been a total nightmare to add a favicon and I have tried many solutions to no avail. The latest solution that has been recommended to me is called 'favicons-webpack-plugin' which can be found here: https://github.com/jantimon/favicons-webpack-plugin.

If anyone can tell me what I am doing wrong, your assistance would be greatly appreciated.

I get the following error when I run 'npm run start'

[image]

This is my directory structure:

[image]

This is my webpack.config.js file:

```
const path = require('path');
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const NpmInstallPlugin = require('npm-install-webpack-plugin');
const TARGET = process.env.npm_lifecycle_event;
const FaviconsWebpackPlugin = require('favicons-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CleanPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var favicons = require('favicons'),
    source = 'my-logo.png',           // Source image(s). `string`, `buffer` or array of `{ size: filepath }`
    configuration = {
        appName: null,                  // Your application's name. `string`
        appDescription: null,           // Your application's description. `string`
        developerName: null,            // Your (or your developer's) name. `string`
        developerURL: null,             // Your (or your developer's) URL. `string`
        background: "#fff",             // Background colour for flattened icons. `string`
        path: "/",                      // Path for overriding default icons path. `string`
        url: "/",                       // Absolute URL for OpenGraph image. `string`
        display: "standalone",          // Android display: "browser" or "standalone". `string`
        orientation: "portrait",        // Android orientation: "portrait" or "landscape". `string`
        version: "1.0",                 // Your application's version number. `number`
        logging: false,                 // Print logs to console? `boolean`
        online: false,                  // Use RealFaviconGenerator to create favicons? `boolean`
        icons: {
            android: true,              // Create Android homescreen icon. `boolean`
            appleIcon: true,            // Create Apple touch icons. `boolean`
            appleStartup: true,         // Create Apple startup images. `boolean`
            coast: true,                // Create Opera Coast icon. `boolean`
            favicons: true,             // Create regular favicons. `boolean`
            firefox: true,              // Create Firefox OS icons. `boolean`
            opengraph: true,            // Create Facebook OpenGraph image. `boolean`
            twitter: true,              // Create Twitter Summary Card image. `boolean`
            windows: true,              // Create Windows 8 tile icons. `boolean`
            yandex: true                // Create Yandex browser icon. `boolean`
        }
    },
    callback = function (error, response) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error.status);  // HTTP error code (e.g. `200`) or `null`
            console.log(error.name);    // Error name e.g. "API Error"
            console.log(error.message); // Error description e.g. "An unknown error has occurred"
        }
        console.log(response.images);   // Array of { name: string, contents: <buffer> }
        console.log(response.files);    // Array of { name: string, contents: <string> }
        console.log(response.html);     // Array of strings (html elements)
    };

favicons(source, configuration, callback);
const pkg = require('./package.json');

const PATHS = {
  app: path.join(__dirname, 'app'),
  build: path.join(__dirname, 'build')
};

process.env.BABEL_ENV = TARGET;

const common = {
  entry: {
    app: PATHS.app
  },
  // Add resolve.extensions
  // '' is needed to allow imports without an extension
  // note the .'s before the extension as it will fail to load without them
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx', '.json']
  },
  output: {
    path: PATHS.build,
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        // Test expects a RegExp! Notethe slashes!
        test: /\.css$/,
        loaders: ['style', 'css'],
        //Include accepts either a path or an array of paths
        include: PATHS.app

      },
      //set up JSX. This accepts js too thanks to RegExp
      {
      test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
      //enable caching for improved performance during development
      //It uses default OS directory by default. If you need something more custom,
      //pass a path to it. ie: babel?cacheDirectory=<path>
      loaders: [
        'babel?cacheDirectory,presets[]=es2015'
    ],
      //parse only app files Without this it will go thru the entire project.
      //beside being slow this will likely result in an error
      include: PATHS.app
      }
    ]
  }
};

// Default configuration. We will return this if
// Webpack is called outside of npm.
if(TARGET === 'start' || !TARGET){
  module.exports = merge(common, {
    devtool: 'eval-source-map',
    devServer: {
      contentBase: PATHS.build,

      //enable history API fallback so HTML5 HISTORY API based
      // routing works. This is a good default that will come in handy in more
      // complicated setups.
      historyApiFallback: true,
      hot: true,
      inline: true,
      progress: true,

      //display only errors to reduce output amount
      stats: 'errors only',

      //Parse host and port from env so this is easy to customize
      host: process.env.HOST,
      port: process.env.PORT

},

plugins: [
  new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
  new NpmInstallPlugin({
    save: true //--save
  }),
  new FaviconsWebpackPlugin('my-logo.png')

]
});
}

if(TARGET === 'build' || TARGET === 'stats') {
  module.exports = merge(common, {
    entry: {
      vendor: Object.keys(pkg.dependencies).filter(function(v) {
        return v !== 'alt-utils';
      }),
      style: PATHS.style
    },
    output: {
      path: PATHS.build,
      // Output using entry name
      filename: '[name].[chunkhash].js',
      chunkFilename: '[chunkhash].js'
    },
    module: {
      loaders: [
        // Extract CSS during build
        {
          test: /\.css$/,
          loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css'),
          include: PATHS.app
        }
      ]
    },
    plugins: [
      // Output extracted CSS to a file
      new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].[chunkhash].css'),
      // Extract vendor and manifest files
      new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
        names: ['vendor', 'manifest']
      }),
      // Setting DefinePlugin affects React library size!
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env.NODE_ENV': '"production"'
      }),
      new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
        compress: {
          warnings: false
        }
      })
    ]
  });
}
```

This is my server.js file:

```
/* Global Requires */

const express    = require('express');
const logger     = require('morgan');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path       = require('path');
const app        = express();
const ReactDOM = require('react-dom')
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');


if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  console.log('in development.');
  require('dotenv').config();
} else {
  console.log('in production.');
}

/* App Config */
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));
app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));

app.use(logger('dev'));

/* Server Initialization */
app.get('/', (req, res) => res.sendFile('index.html'));
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server initialized on // ${new Date()}`));
```

Comment: just make sure its at least 16x16... and favicons vary from browsers - some won't show up unless its exactly 16x16 some 32x32, oh, and use png not jpg..

Comment: Is your issue that webpack isn't bundling your ico file? or is it that the page isn't displaying it. You can use `file-loader` to have wepack load the file to your bundle and then just call it in your html page.

Comment: Hey @CodeYogi, if my solution worked for you, would you want to mark it as the correct answer?

Answer (score 217):

**Here is all you need:**

add this to the plugins:[] section of your webpack.config.js

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    favicon: "./src/favicon.gif"
})
```

That is definitely after adding "favicon.gif" to the folder "src".

This will transfer the icon to your build folder and include it in your  tag like this `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.gif">`. This is safer than just importing with `copyWebpackPLugin`

Comment: This is the most simple and secure way than other response. Good point to you.

Comment: Adding some details to this answer would be helpful, in which file do I add the `new HtmlWebpackPlugin` code? which plugin do I need to install? what config is needed to use this?

Comment: @Sumit You will need `'html-webpack-plugin'`. You can look at their documentation for more details. The example above does not work out of the box, you need to add at least `template` and `filename` options.

Comment: Badass solution.

Comment: I see the favicon on my desktop web browser but it is not shown on my web browser on Android, is this expected? Do I need any particular size or something? I am using a 64x64 png

Answer (score 38):

Adding your favicon simply into to the `public` folder should do. Make sure the favicon is named as `favicon.ico`.

Answer (score 37):

For future googlers:
You can also use [copy-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/copy-webpack-plugin) and add this to webpack's production config:

```
plugins: [
  new CopyWebpackPlugin({ 
    patterns: [ 
     // relative path is from src
     { from: './static/favicon.ico' }, // <- your path to favicon
    ]
 })
]
```

Comment: Hands down the best and most consise solution so far. Mind that my webpack.config.js resides in the root directory so I had to use `./src/favicon.ico` to target the correct path.

Comment: Note that you need to do:

$ npm install copy-webpack-plugin --save-dev

Then at the top of your webpack.config.js add:

const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

Comment: API changed. Now should be:
new CopyWebpackPlugin({ patterns: [
    { from: './static/favicon.ico' },
  ]}),

Comment: Thanks for the notice, I've just updated my answer ⬆️

Answer (score 21):

Here is how I did.

### public/index.html

I have added the generated favicon links.

```
...
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/path/to/favicon-32x32.png" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/path/to/favicon-16x16.png" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/path/to/favicon.ico" type="image/png/ico" />
```

### webpack.config.js

```
new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
   template: '/path/to/index.html',
   favicon: '/path/to/favicon.ico',
})
```

#### Note

I use `historyApiFallback` in dev mode, but I didn't need to have any extra setup to get the favicon work nor on the server side.

Answer (score 12):

Another alternative is

```
npm install react-favicon
```

And in your application you would just do:

```
   import Favicon from 'react-favicon';
   //other codes

    ReactDOM.render(
        <div>
            <Favicon url="/path/to/favicon.ico"/>
            // do other stuff here
        </div>
        , document.querySelector('.react'));
```

Comment: This is a great answer when a favicon is derived from variables in the DOM, thanks for your answer.

Comment: Failing now on safari

Answer (score 11):

The correct answers:

If you are using webpack directly:

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
   favicon: "./public/fav-icon.ico"
})
```

If you use CRA(create-react-app) then you can modificate the `manifest.json` in the public directory

Answer (score 9):

Browsers look for your favicon in `/favicon.ico`, so that's where it needs to be. You can double check if you've positioned it in the correct place by navigating to `[address:port]/favicon.ico` and seeing if your icon appears.

In dev mode, you are using historyApiFallback, so will need to configure webpack to explicitly return your icon for that route:

```
historyApiFallback: {
    index: '[path/to/index]',
    rewrites: [
        // shows favicon
        { from: /favicon.ico/, to: '[path/to/favicon]' }
    ]
}
```

In your `server.js` file, try explicitly rewriting the url:

```
app.configure(function() {
    app.use('/favicon.ico', express.static(__dirname + '[route/to/favicon]'));
});
```

(or however your setup prefers to rewrite urls)

I suggest generating a true `.ico` file rather than using a `.png`, since I've found that to be more reliable across browsers.

Answer (score 6):

It's the same as adding any other external script or stylesheet. 
All you have to do is focus on giving the **correct path** and **rel** and **type**.

Note: When my favicon image was in the *assets folder*, it was *not displaying the favicon*. So I *copied the image to the same folder as of my index.html* and it worked perfectly as it should.

```
<head>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png/ico" href="/favicon.png" />
    <title>SITE NAME</title>
</head>
```

It worked for me. Hope it works for you too.

Answer (score 3):

I use [favicons-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/favicons-webpack-plugin)

```
const FaviconsWebpackPlugin = require("favicons-webpack-plugin");

module.exports={
plugins:[
    new FaviconsWebpackPlugin("./public/favicon.ico"),
//public is in the root folder in this app. 

]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me. Add the following in `index.html` (inside src folder along with favicon.ico)

```
<link rel="icon" href="/src/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
```

Within `webpack.config.js` add to your plugins

```
 plugins: [
     new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
         template: './src/index.html'
     })
 ],
```

Comment: this implementation is wrong. Should have added favicon inside HtmlWebpackPlugin

Answer (score 2):

Use the **file-loader** for that:

```
{
    test: /\.(svg|png|gif|jpg|ico)$/,
    include: path.resolve(__dirname, path),
    use: {
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
            context: 'src/assets',
            name: 'root[path][name].[ext]'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should also add the favicon with `HtmlWebpackPlugin` for work correctly, not only that.

Answer (score 2):

I will give simple steps to add favicon  :-)

- Create your logo and save as `logo.png`
- Change `logo.png` to `favicon.ico`

  > Note **:** when you save it is `favicon.ico` make sure it's not `favicon.ico.png`
- It might take some time to update

  > change icon size in manifest.json if you can't wait

Comment: Instead of modify `manifest.json`, you should clear the cache on the browser. On Chrome it's `cmd + shift + r`/`ctrl + shift + r`.

Answer (score 2):

Replace the favicon.ico in your public folder with yours, that should get you going.

Answer (score 1):

In my case -- I am running Visual Studio (Professional 2017) in debug mode with webpack 2.4.1 -- it was necessary to put the `favicon.ico` into the root directory of the project, right where the folder `src` is rather than in a folder `public`, even though according to https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder the latter should be the official location.

Answer (score 1):

`Ctrl+f5` clear your browser cache

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still searching... I managed to import the favicon in my index.html once I ran
`npm install html-loader`
And included the following in my `webpack.config.js`:

```
// ... Other config options.
{
  test: /\.html$/,
  include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public'), // Your path may be different.
  use: [
      {
          loader: 'html-loader',
      },
  ],
},
```

The file paths need to be relative to your source code, not the production code.
To check if the your build includes the favicon you can look up the production path in the url like this: `localhost:xxxxx/path/to/favicon.png`

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answers mentioning **CopyWebpackPlugin** and **HtmlWebpackPlugin** are both adequate.

*However, it is worth noting two things*:

1. **CopyWebpackPlugin** is a *"third-party package maintained by community members, it potentially does not have the same support, security policy or license as webpack, and it is not maintained by webpack."* - Hence why there are comments saying it is less safe.
2. The benefit of using **CopyWebpackPlugin** is that you can specify the output folder (i.e. **/public/images** - This will place your favicon in **dist/public/images** and your HTML file can access it there). **HtmlWebpackPlugin** will put the favicon in the root of the dist folder, meaning less flexibility in your input of how the **dist** folder is structured.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).