# favicon to react application doesn't work

Tags: reactjs

I want to add a favicon to my react application but it doesn't seem to working.

Tried the below: 
add the code to the index.html file in the head section

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/apple-touch-icon.png">

<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/favicon-32x32.png">

<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/favicon-16x16.png">

<link rel="manifest" href="/site.webmanifest">

<link rel="mask-icon" href="/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#5bbad5">

<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#ffc40d">

<meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
```

Also placed the icons in the same folder as index.html. Could you please let me know where the problem persists.

Thanks.

Comment: For favicon try using ico files instead of png

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a browser tab icon (favicon) for a website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888377/how-to-add-a-browser-tab-icon-favicon-for-a-website)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add Favicon with React and Webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37298215/add-favicon-with-react-and-webpack)

Comment: Is the favicon in the folder after you build the app? Do you get a console error saying it can't find the icon?

Comment: I dont see any error on the console...to test if it actually works i place the ico files and other .png files in the same location as index.html file. so the directory structure is folder->app->index.hml and favicon.ico

Answer (score 1):

Remember to add `%PUBLIC_URL%` to all your href attributes in `index.html`

For example;

`<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/apple-touch-icon.png">`

That should fix your issue.

Comment: URIError: Failed to decode param '/%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon-32x32.png this is the error i get in the console.

Comment: There is no "/" in front of %PUBLIC_URL%