# How to add favicon to react application browser tab (duplicate)

Tags: reactjs, favicon

I am new to react. Could someone help me in adding favicon to react application. I have created favicon package and added generated code to `index.html`. But I am not knowing how this `href` to favicon to be specified.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add Favicon with React and Webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37298215/add-favicon-with-react-and-webpack)

Answer (score 10):

You can add favicon.ico to public/images then enter the index.html and add the code.

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="./images/favicon.ico">
```

Answer (score 7):

if you have your own image then simply change this line to your image address

```
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
```

just change the favicon.ico to your image name

```
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/coolImage.png">
```

Answer (score 2):

If anyone is looking in 2021.
Place your image in the Public folder and change the following icons with your ones on the following page.

> /pubic/index.html

```
  <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/youricon.svg" />
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/youricon.svg" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Move your favicon image in public folder. 
Rename in manifesto.json name of favicon. 
Update link in index.html

Answer (score 0):

just rename your image with favicon.ico in public directory and it will get that img as favicon icon for your react project.

Thank You.

File name changed as favicon.ico

[image: file name changed as favicon.ico]

Answer (score 0):

To change browser tab Icon just get into index.html file then as follows :-

If your img is icon then follows the below syntax :-

```
<link rel="icon" href="./book_icon.ico" />
```

If your img is png/jpg then follows the below syntax :-

```
<link rel="icon" href="./book_PNG.png" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to generate multiple versions using a generator like [this one](https://www.favicon-generator.org/). Since there are now multiple sizes instead of the usual one-size-fits-all, place all the images in **public/favicons/** then update `<head>`.

Firstly, delete these since you'll be placing your own:

```html
<link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon-16x16.png" />
```

Paste the new markup and update each one to use the correct path by prefixing it with `%PUBLIC_URL%/favicons/`. Take note to also update the path for *manifest.json*.

```html
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicons/apple-icon-57x57.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicons/apple-icon-60x60.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicons/apple-icon-72x72.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicons/apple-icon-76x76.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicons/apple-icon-114x114.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicons/apple-icon-120x120.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicons/apple-icon-144x144.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicons/apple-icon-152x152.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicons/apple-icon-180x180.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="192x192"  href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicons/android-icon-192x192.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicons/favicon-32x32.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="96x96" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicons/favicon-96x96.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicons/favicon-16x16.png">
<link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicons/manifest.json">
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#46179c">
<meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicons/ms-icon-144x144.png">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#46179c">
```

Lastly, delete the default **manifest.json** file as you'll now be using the one in your `public/favicons/` folder. Update the image paths in **/public/favicons/manifest.json**.