# Favicon not displaying on staging server

Tags: html, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

Please help this here i'm trying to display title with logo on tab But in local it's working fine but staging server not displaying the logo.

```
<title>Global</title>   

<link type="image/png" href="src/assets/images/logo/bigImage.png" rel="shortcut icon" />
```

Comment: Can you logo image path?

Comment: ya now i added logo image path

Answer (score 0):

It's the same as adding any other external script or stylesheet. All you have to do is focus on giving the correct path and rel and type.

Note: When my favicon image was in the assets folder, it was not displaying the favicon. So I copied the image to the same folder as of my index.html and it worked perfectly as it should.

```
<head>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png/ico" href="/favicon.png" />
    <title>SITE NAME</title>
</head>
```

It worked for me. I hope it works for you too.

You can also check some more answers here: [Add Favicon with React and Webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37298215/add-favicon-with-react-and-webpack/51925112#51925112)

Comment: Where is favicon icon is there same location only i added but again not displaying on staging server

Comment: <title>Global</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="../public/assets/images/TalentPoollogo.png" />      added like this still its not working, please help me.

Comment: Your index.html and icon must be in the same folder i.e. public. Then why are you importing again from the public folder by going one up first on the tree.
**href="../public/assets/images/TalentPoollogo.png"**
It should be **href="./assets/images/TalentPoollogo.png"**

Comment: <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png/ico" href="./assets/images/favicon.ico" /> this is not working in local and staging both.

Comment: F:\desuvit\projects\workingbranch\TalentPool.WebApp\public\assets\images

Comment: I meant something like this: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/folder-structure-of-react-application/Images/Folder%20Structure%20of%20React.png