# How to add favicon in react application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, html-webpack-plugin, webpack-plugin

I want to add favicon in my react application. I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37298215/add-favicon-with-react-and-webpack) post and followed but it is not working in my case. I added favicon.ico inside public folder where index.html is present.
This is my directory structure
[image]

This is the snippet of my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8'>
    <meta name='color-scheme' content='light'>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'>
    <title>My App</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="./public/favicon.ico"></link>
    <script src="/env-config.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>   
  </body>
</html>
```

This is the snippet of my webpack.config.js

```
const { webpackConfig, webpackMerge, htmlOverlay } = require('just-scripts');
const webpack = require('webpack')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = webpackMerge.merge(
  webpackConfig({}),
  htmlOverlay({
    template: 'public/index.html'
  }),
  {
    output: {
      publicPath: '/'
    },
    devServer: {
      historyApiFallback: true
    },
    plugins:[
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({ 
        'process.env.API_URL': JSON.stringify(process.env.API_URL)
      }),
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        favicon: './public/favicon.ico',
      })
    ]
  }
);
```

I added HtmlWebpackPlugin as shown above but getting this error on npm run build

```
ERROR in Conflict: Multiple assets emit different content to the same filename index.html

webpack 5.73.0 compiled with 1 error in 72911 ms
[12:42:26 pm] x Error detected while running 'webpack'
[12:42:26 pm] x ------------------------------------
[12:42:26 pm] x Webpack failed with 1 error(s).
[12:42:26 pm] x ------------------------------------
[12:42:26 pm] x finished 'build' in 87.6s with errors
[12:42:26 pm] x Error previously detected. See above for error messages.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! test-report-fluent-single@0.1.0 build: `just-scripts build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the test-report-fluent-single@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

When I removed the HtmlWebpackPlugin, the build is successful but I am not seeing the favicon.ico in the dist folder and also the favicon is not visible in the browser.

I am able to see the favicon only at the homepage and I checked the network tab and getting 304 ok status on http://localhost:8080/public/favicon.ico
But when I render other components and navigate to different url, I am getting 404 Not found on http://localhost:8080/home/public/favicon.ico

I also tried adding %PUBIC_URL%/ in index.html href before the path of favicon but getting the error of

```
URIError: Failed to decode param '/%PUBLIC_URL%/public/favicon.ico'
```

And in network tab I am getting 400 Bad Request error on http://localhost:8080/%PUBLIC_URL%/public/favicon.ico

In this case I am able to see the favicon in localhost with errors in console but not able to see icon when I deploy my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you can try :
chagne `favicon.ico` and try a `svg file` `href="./public/favicon.svg"`

**if this doesn't work:**

add this new rule to your `webpack.config.json`:

```
module: {
    // configuration regarding modules
    rules: [
          {
            test: /\.(svg|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
          }
```

Comment: What should be the contents of index.html?

Comment: Where should I put the 'rules' in my webpack.config.js file. Could you point out in my above code snippet. I tried putting it in inside webpackConfig({}) but getting error of unknown property. I also tried putting it below plugins but getting the same error.

Comment: If you scroll down you file you will get `module: {
    // configuration regarding modules
    rules: [` inside it you can add this lines `{test:........exclude:....}`

Comment: first try the first method. add a `icon.svg` then try. I have made a change in my post

Comment: Tried the svg method but still getting the issue of 404 not found for favicon.svg when I am navigating to different component url.

Comment: I can not see the module: {     // configuration regarding modules     rules: [
inside my webpack.config.js file.
I pasted the whole file in my post above. Please point out the line where can I put the rules.

Comment: The above rule is present in fileOverlay.ts inside just-scripts webpack. I have included that in my webpack.config.js and webpack.serve.config.js files. Please refer this for info - https://microsoft.github.io/just/scripts/webpack.html
I can now see favicon.svg in my dist folder but I am still getting the same issue of 404 when rendering to other components with different url